# Is there a built-in IsLowerCase() in .NET?

Tags: .net, string

Is there a built-in `IsLowerCase()` in .NET?

Comment: The implementation's only trivial until you need to consider other locales...

Comment: Is this for a string or just a char?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do you mean `Char.IsLower(ch);` ?

Answer (score 7):

```
public static bool IsLowerCase( this string text ) {
    if ( string.IsNullOrEmpty( text ) ) { return true; }
    foreach ( char c in text )
        if ( char.IsLetter( c ) && !char.IsLower( c ) )
            return false;

    return true;
}


"someString".IsLowerCase();
```

Answer (score 3):

Keep in mind that localization makes this a non-trivial question.  The first example is fine as long as you don't care:

```
string s = ...
s.All(c => char.IsLower(c));
```

If you do care, do it this way:

```
s.ToLower(CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture) == s;
```

This gives you the chance to address culture issues.

Comment: Why not s.All(c => char.IsLower(c))?

Comment: dalle: You need to do a String.ToCharArray() before you can do lambda expressions on characters. That is, bool isStringLower = str.ToCharArray().All(c => char.IsLower(c));

Comment: @DrJokepu: Actually, you don't need to do ToCharArray() before you can do the lambda - I just tested it, it works fine on a string too...

Comment: @DrJokepu: According to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string_members.aspx#extensionMethodTableToggle you don't need it.

Comment: Ahh, I think IntelliSense just supresses them on string.  I'll modify my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Edit: Didn't see the actual meaning of your question.  You could use:

```
char.IsLower(c);
```

As far as easily converting between cases:

Sure is:

[MSDN says](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/312890):

```
 string upper = "CONVERTED FROM UPPERCASE";
 Console.WriteLine(upper.ToLower());
```

It's part of the `string` class.

There's also the `TextInfo` class:

```
CultureInfo cultureInfo   = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;
TextInfo textInfo = cultureInfo.TextInfo;

Console.WriteLine(textInfo.ToTitleCase(title));
Console.WriteLine(textInfo.ToLower(title));
Console.WriteLine(textInfo.ToUpper(title));
```

Which allows for more variation to change caps and whatnot (like `ToTitleCase`).

Comment: I think what he is asking is if there is a function that identifies a lower case string

Answer (score 1):

As others have mentioned you can easily do this for a single char using char.IsLower(ch)

But to extend the String primitive, it wouldn't be very difficult.  You can extend the BCL relatively simply using the Runtime.CompilerServices namespace:

```
Imports System.Runtime.CompilerServices
Module CustomExtensions

    <Extension()> _
    Public Function IsLowerCase(ByVal Input As String) As Boolean
        Return Return Input.All(Function(c) Char.IsLower(c))
    End Function

End Module
```

Or in C#, that would be:

```
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices; 
static class CustomExtensions 
{ 
    public static bool IsLowerCase(this string Input) 
    { 
        return Input.All(c => char.IsLower(c)); 
    }
}
```

Now you can figure it out using:

```
Console.WriteLine("ThisIsMyTestString".IsLowerCase())
```

Which would return false because there are upper case characters contained within the string.

Comment: simply "return Input.All(c => char.IsLower(c))" is enough, and faster since it can return as soon as it finds the first upper case letter.

Comment: Ah, nice...I never noticed you could do an All on a String object... thanks.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
public bool IsLower(string TestString)
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(TestString))
        {
            return true;
        }

        string testlower = TestString.ToLowerInvariant();

        if (String.Compare(TestString, testlower, false) == 0)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }


    }
```

Comment: Long windedness is intentional in this case. And yeah, i think asd234as!!!df is lower case. 2,3,4 and ! by definition don't have case at all so are both lower and upper case.

Answer (score 0):

balabaster,
please do not use this approach with FindAll/Count. All you need is

```
return Input.ToList().Exists(c => Char.IsUpper(c));
```

It will stop the iteration on the first upper case character.FindAll create a new List and you use only the Count property. If we have a long string that's in upper case, you will end up with a copy of the original string.

Comment: @Petrov: .All (as I have used) drops out on the first existence of a non-lowercase character.  What you've suggested is equally long winded.  If you drop the ToList().Exists() and use instead just .All(c => char.IsLower(c)) then you get even better results!

Answer (score -1):

Guys why this LINQ abuse (ToList(), ToArray(), All(), Any(), ...) ? I love LINQ and lambdas too but in this case I think the good old foreach is what we need. See the answer of TcKs as reference - but we can do better if we remove the superfluous

```
char.IsLetter( c )
```

because IsLower() is doing the same check.

Comment: Because a nice .All(c => Char.IsLower(c)) takes care of the whole lot... forget iterating over a collection - just query it like you would a table in a database.  Much more elegant...